# java.lang.InternalError: instrument library is missing in target VM

Tags: java, jvm, internal

I'm using an API and encountered a very unusual error which is occurring from the API itself:

```
Exception in thread "11748 - Development Toolkit" java.lang.InternalError: instrument library is missing in target VM
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(pp:36)
    at nul.IiiIIIiiiiii.for(xnb:206)
    at nul.IIiIiIiIIIII.run(cmb:31)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: Failed to load agent library
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.execute(sw:86)
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(pp:17)
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(pp:135)
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(pp:87)
    ... 2 more
```

Unfortunately I don't have much context on the exception as the the APIs source is closed and Google doesn't find many results on it. However my question is what is generally the nature of such an errors occurrence and how one would typically fix and potentially avoid it in the future. I'm using a 32-Bit VM on a 64-Bit OS if that helps at all, Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a corrupted Java installation.  Try removing and reinstalling the JDK.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'll do that right now and get back to you.

Comment: @JimGarrison So unfortunately the same error persists. I've updated my post providing additional info on the VM and OS version.